# Update ngModel on a directive, from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm having trouble understanding why changes to an ngModel doesn't propagate from one directive to another. [Here's a plunker that shows a simplified version of what we're trying to do](http://plnkr.co/edit/dsybDpmKvjQfE2BsDbev?p=preview).

Basically, I've declared a directive which uses ngModel, and an isolate scope:

```
.directive('echo', function() {
    var link = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        // --- 8< ---
        scope.$watch(attrs['ngModel'], function() {
            scope.model = ngModel.$modelValue;
            console.log("***** Echo model updated: ", scope.model);
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: link,
        scope: {
            id: "="
        }
    }
})
```

That directive is then wrapped by another directive, also with a dependency on ngModel and with an isolate scope:

```
.directive('wrapper', function() {
    var link = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.$watch(attrs['ngModel'], function() {
            var model = ngModel.$modelValue;
            console.log("----- Wrapper model updated", model);

            scope.model = model;
        })
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: link,
        scope: {
        },

        template: "<div><h2>Echo:</h2> <echo id='myEcho' ng-model='model'></echo></div><div><h2>Model text:</h2>{{ model.text }}</div>"
    }
})
```

You can see that the "wrapper" directive requires an `ngModel`, as does the `echo` directive.

When I use the "wrapper" directive in my HTML, and then I push a value into the ngModel, the "wrapper" directive correctly identifies that the model has changed (the console.log shows this). At that point, the wrapper directive then updates the model on its scope, which I would have *expected* would propagate that model update into the "echo" directive.

However, watching the console, the "echo" directive never sees the model get updated.

**Q: Why doesn't the "echo" directive see the updated model from the "wrapper" directive?**

Note: This may be made slightly more complex by the fact that the "echo" is not *only* consumed from the "wrapper" directive - sometimes it is consumed directly.

Comment: 3 minute video about `the dot` will likely help you  https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot

Comment: Thanks, I don't think that's the issue here though. This answer is a really good explanation of that video: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

No, the issue does not relate to timing - watches will still fire whether they have been added before or after the watched value has been set.

I would recommend putting some breakpoints in your `echo` directive and stepping through to see how the watchers are being set.

Here is an updated plunker that is working: http://plnkr.co/edit/bbv2vpZ7KaDiblVcoaNX?p=preview

```
.directive('echo', function() {
    var link = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        console.log("***** Linking echo");

        var render = function (val) {
            var htmlText = val || 'n/t';
            element.html(htmlText);
        };
        scope.$watch("model.text", render);
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: link,
        scope: {
            id: "=",
            model: '=echoModel'
        }
    }
})

.directive('wrapper', function() {
    var link = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        console.log("---- Linking Wrapper");
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: link,
        scope: {
          wrapperModel: '=ngModel'
        },

        template: "<div><h2>Echo:</h2> <echo id='myEcho' echo-model='wrapperModel'></echo></div><div><h2>Model text:</h2>{{ wrapperModel.text }}</div>"
    }
})
```

---

The reason it's not working is because of the way the `attrs` and watchers work which might be a little unexpected.

Basically you're trying to watch the `scope.model` property on your scope, not the evaluated value of the `ngModel` attribute as you might expect:

```
.directive('echo', function() {
    var link = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        // Your HTML is `<echo ng-model='model'></echo>`
        // which means this `scopePropertyToWatch` will have the value 'model'.
        var scopePropertyToWatch = attrs['ngModel'];

        // This means it will try to watch the value
        // of `scope.model`, which isn't right because
        // it hasn't been set.
        scope.$watch(scopePropertyToWatch, function() {
            scope.model = ngModel.$modelValue;
            console.log("***** Echo model updated: ", scope.model);
        });
    };

    // ...
})
```

There are two simple solutions.

**1. Setup two-way binding on the `ngModel` attribute:**

```
.directive('echo', function() {
    var link = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        // Watch the `scope.ngModel` property on the scope.
        // NOT the attr['ngModel'] value which will still
        // be 'model'.
        scope.$watch('ngModel', function() {
            scope.model = ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
            console.log("***** Echo model updated: ", scope.model);
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: link,
        scope: {
            id: "=",
            ngModel: "=" // This will make the `ngModel` property available on the scope.
        }
    }
});
```

It gets a bit complex using `ngModel` the way you are - I'd recommend having a look at this video on how to use ngModel in custom components: [Jason Aden - Using ngModelController to Make Sexy Custom Components](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVzymluqmg4)

**2. Watch the property on the $parent scope:**

```
.directive('echo', function() {
    var link = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        // Add a watch on the **parent** scope for the attribute value.
        // NOTE that we use the attrs['ngModel'] value because the property
        // on the parent scope **is**: `scope.$parent.model`
        scope.$parent.$watch(attrs['ngModel'], function() {
            scope.model = ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
            console.log("***** Echo model updated: ", scope.model);
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: link,
        scope: {
            id: "="
        }
    }
});
```

Again, it can get a little complex using `ngModelCtrl.$modelValue` but at least that will get your watchers firing.

Comment: Hmm, your explanation doesn't make sense to me :-(. The wrapper directive and the echo directive are essentially the same - but the wrapper directive updates properly, yet the echo directive doesn't. Why? I think the answer from @ben-priebe may be "more correct" - it seems to be something to do with the order that the directives execute. I don't understand why the order is important though, since I thought setting up a watch on an expression wouldn't be dependent on timing. His plunk has a bug but here's one that works: http://plnkr.co/edit/dsybDpmKvjQfE2BsDbev?p=preview

Comment: Your updated plunker was fantastic, by the way - it made me realise that I was overcomplicating things (by watching for changes in the ngModel then pushing that to the scope as a 'model'). Your way is much simpler. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome :) It's a good process to go through, getting an understanding of the nuances of directives and the scope.